# Proof of the Poincare inequality for $W_0^{1,2}((a,b))$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

I have a question about an exercise for which I already have the solution, which I do not unterstand completely.

Let $a, b \in \mathbb R$ with $0 < a < b$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
\|u\|^2_{L_2(a,b)} \le \frac{(b-a)^2}{2} \|u'\|^2_{L_2(a,b)}
\end{align*}
for all $u \in \overset{\circ}{W}_{1,2}((a,b))$.
The latter space denotes the closure of the test function space with the Sobolev-norm.

Proof:
By the Sobolev embedding theorem we know that $\overset{\circ}{W}_{1,2}((a,b))$ is continously embedded in the space $C([a,b])$. Thus we can write $u \in \overset{\circ}{W}_{1,2}((a,b))$ as
\begin{align*}
u(x) = \int_a^x u'(y) \, \mathrm dy, \quad \forall x \in (a,b).
\end{align*}
Why is this possible or why does that follow from the fact that $u$ is continuous?
Then (summarized), we get for $x \in (a,b)$ that
\begin{align*}
|u(x)| \le \|u'\|_{L_2(a,b)} (x-a)^{1/2}
\end{align*}
and afterwards one can conclude that
\begin{align*}
\|u\|^2_{L_2(a,b)} \le \frac{(b-a)^2}{2} \|u'\|^2_{L_2(a,b)}.
\end{align*}

I really understand the second part of the proof but not the first one.